# Chrome Extension: Not allowed to load local resource

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a chrome extension to modify a website, and I'm having trouble loading a web-font.

After my webpack build, I generate a `dist` folder. Inside this folder, I have a `main.css` that contains this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url(chrome://extensions/dilogbnjbadifdhdphnncpfndfocidle/fontawesome-webfont.eot);
  src: url(chrome://extensions/dilogbnjbadifdhdphnncpfndfocidle/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.6.3) format('embedded-opentype'), url(chrome://extensions/dilogbnjbadifdhdphnncpfndfocidle/fontawesome-webfont.woff2) format('woff2'), url(chrome://extensions/dilogbnjbadifdhdphnncpfndfocidle/fontawesome-webfont.woff) format('woff'), url(chrome://extensions/dilogbnjbadifdhdphnncpfndfocidle/fontawesome-webfont.ttf) format('truetype'), url(chrome://extensions/dilogbnjbadifdhdphnncpfndfocidle/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular) format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

This is my webpack `publicPath`:

> chrome://extensions/dilogbnjbadifdhdphnncpfndfocidle

All files are on the dist folder.

This is my relevant `manifest` configuration:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "fontawesome-webfont.eot",
    "fontawesome-webfont.svg",
    "fontawesome-webfont.ttf",
    "fontawesome-webfont.woff",
    "fontawesome-webfont.woff2"
  ],
```

PS: I've tried **everything** on the `web_accessible_resources` section, including `*.[format]`, `*.*` and others.

This is the error I get:

> Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://extensions/dilogbnjbadifdhdphnncpfndfocidle/fontawesome-webfont.woff2

Screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBTi4.png]

This is the `dist` folder I set as the extension root directory:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yItCE.png]

What may I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct scheme is `chrome-extension://`.
See also [i18n API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n#overview-predefined) for the list of allowed constants in JS/CSS files:

> The special message **@@extension_id** can be used in the CSS and JavaScript files, whether or not the extension or app is localized. This message doesn't work in manifest files.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url(chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/fontawesome-webfont.eot);
  /* ............. */
}
```

Comment: perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Hello I get File Not Found with this: `window.open("chrome-extension://cgfdoidimkkegpikmhlmmdlacnncnjma","","","false");` and I get Not allowed to load local resource with this `window.open("chrome://extensions/?id=cgfdoidimkkegpikmhlmmdlacnncnjma","","","false");`